# How can I add [ ] in Declaration using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Need a bit help plz..
I'm trying to write a declaration using XSL i-e.

```
<!DOCTYPE ADI SYSTEM "ADI.DTD"[]>
```

My code is :

```
<xsl:output method="ADI" 
    doctype-system="ADI.DTD"
    encoding="iso-8859-1"
    indent="yes" />
```

Which gives me :

```
<!DOCTYPE ADI SYSTEM "ADI.DTD">
```

I'm only missing    [ ]   at the end of `"ADI>DTD"` and then > (tag is closed)

do you guys know how we can add [ ] in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no internal doctype, the brackets may be ommitted. Empty brackets have the exactly same definition like no brackets have. Whether to add them or not is not defined by the standard and implementation-dependent.

XSLT does not know any flag to set that behavior, but there might be implementation specific ones.